# Can broadband over powerline carry 2 signals over the same power line?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

Can [broadband over powerline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband_over_power_lines#Standards) carry 2 signals over the same power line ? If so how does it decode them and know which data stream its looking for. Eg. with a cat6 network each device has its own cable running back to the network switch, but with a powerline network it seems the data will all be running over the same line ?

The reason i ask is because we are currently looking at installing a Sky Q (Sky is the UK satellite television provider, and the Q range is their latest product line up that allows set top boxes in rooms that do not have a coaxial ports) they do this by distributing the AV data over the homes powerlines, i would guess in a similar way to an HDbaseT AV matrix would distribute HMDI video and audio over Cat6. Sky Q seems to run exclusively over the powerline, with no option for running it through a cat5e / cat6 or wifi network.

Comment: It sure can have multiple signals - you think they are offering it only to a single customer in the country? It is standard multiplexing, probably (hopefully) encrypted.

Comment: WiFi does it, too. :D Here’s the relevant entry point on Wikipedia: [Channel access method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_access_method). Of special interest are TDMA and FDMA.

Comment: Actually, despite the comment in the question, Ethernet also uses multiplexing.  The one cable from the switch/hub to each station is just an artifact of how people build simple Ethernets.

Answer (score 4):

I use TP link power line adapters at home, and we have 5 of them dotted around the house. 1 for the router, 4 for rooms in the house. All 5 can communicate.

Its an interesting question, and I have just done some research on whether or not the devices are half-duplex, or full duplex (In other words, they can send and receive at the same time.)

Providers like [netgear](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20233/~/product-faq%3A-powerline-adapters?cid=wmt_netgear_organic) Say their devices are full duplex. In otherwords they can send and receive at the same time. In order to achieve this they will use what is called [multiplexing](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4695/handson-powerline-networking-how-well-or-not-are-latestgeneration-devices-working/2). The long story short is that multiplexing allows several signals to go down the same line at the same time. They are at different frequencies and therefore do not interfere with eachother.

The best example of this is wireless. 2.4ghz has 14 channels (Yes there is some overlap and therefore interference in this case!) for communication to be spread across. If I talk on channel 1 and you talk on channel 6, we should not interfere with eachother.

Comment: One thing that isn't clear from your answer: sending & receiving are on different frequencies, but that's not the same as multiple powerline adapters using different channels on the same network.  My (admittedly poor) understanding is that even on a Wi-Fi network, multiple channels are available, but devices on the same network share the same channel.  Your multiple adapters might work only because you have the bandwidth.  If they're all communicating with the router, it seems like they would all need to be on the same channel unless there's pairing and channel assignment going on.  Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting point. You do have to pair the devices. Lets say Im working from the beggining of when I first installed my plugs. I plug two devices in and pair them. They will now talk. If I plug in a third, tell one of the two devices to pair, and then this new one to pair, they will all talk. You are correct in thinking they must all talk the same way. Im curious how that works being they are all full duplex. If they were half duplex I could tell you with confidence they are using token ring. But they are full. One possibility is that they could agree to talk on one frequency and listen on all